# Is it possible to have limit points in a finite $T_1$ space

Tags: general-topology

Consider a finite $T_1$ topological space $(X,T)= \{x_1, x_2,...x_n\}$ . According to the definition of a $T_1$ space, every singleton is a closed set. I am wondering if you can have limit points in this type of space.

My attempt:
Suppose $x_1$ is a limit point of $(X,T)$, then since B:=$\{x_2,...x_n \}$ is a closed set (a finite union of closed sets), the complement of $B$ is an open set containing $x_1$ that contains no other elements of the topology, therefore $x_1$ is not a limit point, a contradiction. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yep. In fact, it's not difficult to show that $T$ is the discrete topology.

Comment: @TheoBendit: so the answer to the question in the title is "no". Maybe you should clarify your comment or get the OP to reword the question.

Comment: Rob Arthan makes a good point. The question I was answering with "Yep" was the last question: "Am I on the right track", not the question posed in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

As Theo Bendit commented, you are right. You have shown that all one-point subsets are open, i.e. that $X$ is discrete. In a discrete $X$ no point is  a limit point.